# Python: loading text with 3 columns of data

Tags: python, list, import, iterable-unpacking

I have a text file with 3 columns of data I want to plot.

```
from numpy import *
import pylab
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

datalist = loadtxt("datagrid.txt")
x, t, u = datalist[:, 0, 0], datalist[0, :, 0], datalist[0, 0, :]

fig = pylab.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection = '3d')
ax.plot(x, t, u)
pylab.show()
```

I am told too many indices.  How can I unpack a text file with 3 columns if I can only use 2 indices?

Comment: you would probably need to do something like `ax.plot(x,t);ax.plot(u,t)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand correctly, the file `"datagrid.txt"` contains something like

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 9 0
. . .
. . .
. . .
```

If so, then `loadtxt` loads it as **two-dimensional** array. Hence, you need to change the line setting `x`, `t`, and `u` into:

```
x, t, u = datalist[:,0], datalist[:,1], datalist[:,2]
```

or even simpler and more Pythonic:

```
x, t, u = datalist.transpose()
```

or as the third option, read your file as:

```
x, t, u = loadtxt("datagrid.txt", unpack=True)
```

Comment: is there a way to have this plot as a density plot or a color gradient?

Comment: What exactly do you want to plot? Which variable `x`, `t`, `u` should be on what axis, which should correspond to color?